# Format String yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +timezone into DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, timezone

I need to format a String that looks like this:

```
"2018-07-20 18:53:46.598000 +02:00:00"
```

into a DateTime object like this:

```
20/07/2018 (HH with Timezone applied):53:46
```

My approach has been:

```
String dateTimePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern);                                                                                                                                                         
Date feUltModDateTime = dateTimeFormat.parse(feUltMod);
feUltMod = feUltModDateTime.toString();
```

But I'm getting a parse error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-07-20 18:53:46.598000 +02:00:00"
```

Comment: What is `feUltMod` ?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String to Date Conversion mm/dd/yy to YYYY-MM-DD in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405211/string-to-date-conversion-mm-dd-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-java) and/or of [Parsing from String to Date throws Unparsable Date Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514017/parsing-from-string-to-date-throws-unparsable-date-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter origFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS XXXXX");
    DateTimeFormatter desiredFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss");
    ZoneId desiredZone = ZoneId.of("America/Fort_Nelson");

    String feUltMod = "2018-07-20 18:53:46.598000 +02:00:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(feUltMod, origFormatter);
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeWithTimeZoneApplied = dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(desiredZone);
    feUltMod = dateTimeWithTimeZoneApplied.format(desiredFormatter);
    System.out.println(feUltMod);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 20/07/2018 09:53:46

Generally you need two formatters for converting a date or date-time from one format to another: one that specifies the format to convert *from* and one that specifies the format to convert *to*.

> into a DateTime object like this

A date-time object doesn’t have a format, so in that respect cannot be “like this”. `dateTimeWithTimeZoneApplied` in the above snippet is in the specified time zone, so has the hours adjusted. After converting to this time zone I have formatted into a string in the format you mentioned, in case you wanted this (I didn’t find it clear).

I am using and recommending java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The date and time classes you were using, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated and poorly designed, it’s not worth struggling with them. Also `SimpleDateFormat` supports only milliseconds so can only work correctly with exactly 3 decimals on the seconds, not with the 6 decimals you have got.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: You be the boss

Answer (score 0):

```
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    Date df = new Date();
    String yourString = sdf.format(df);

    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(yourString);
    Timestamp sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

The above code will give you current Timestamp.Timestamp will provide better feasibilty

Comment: I fail to see how this might answer the question. Your code just gave `2018-08-17 13:20:00.0` on my computer, not the `20/07/2018 (HH with Timezone applied):53:46` that was asked for. Also you should avoid the outdated and poorly designed date-time classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).